# SQL : How to stock hours into shift times?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I really need a help to find the right SQL logic to get the expected result (third table).
I have to store hours from a table A linked to a table B which contains presence shift times.

It's not important in my exercise to store hours into morning or afternoon shift.
I can stack mechanically into shift time, sorted by project num for example.

TABLE A - effective hours

| name | project number | hours qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MR MARTIN | PROJECT 1 | 1 |
| MR MARTIN | PROJECT 2 | 2 |
| MR MARTIN | PROJECT 3 | 1 |
| MR SMITH | PROJECT 1 | 4 |

TABLE B - presence shift time

| name | AM start time | AM end time | PM start time | PM end time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MR MARTIN | 9:00 | 12:00 | 14:00 | 17:00 |
| MR SMITH | 10:00 | 12:00 | 13:00 | 16:00 |

RESULT I WOULD LIKE TO GET :

| name | project number | start time | end time | hours qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MR MARTIN | PROJECT 1 | 9:00 | 10:00 | 1 |
| MR MARTIN | PROJECT 2 | 10:00 | 12:00 | 2 |
| MR MARTIN | PROJECT 3 | 14:00 | 15:00 | 1 |
| MR MARTIN | NO PROJECT | 15:00 | 17:00 | 2 |
| MR SMITH | PROJECT 1 | 10:00 | 12:00 | 2 |
| MR SMITH | PROJECT 1 | 13:00 | 15:00 | 2 |
| MR SMITH | NO PROJECT | 15:00 | 16:00 | 1 |

If you can help me, I would like to offer a beer ;)

Thank you very much.

Comment: which DBMS are you using ?

Comment: Hi Selvazi. I work with oracle 10g DB.

Answer (score 0):

You can unpivot the AM and PM shifts and then calculate a running total for hours for the shifts and the projects and join the two when the hours overlap (tested on Oracle 11g as 10g is very old):

```
WITH shifts AS (
  SELECT name,
         shift,
         start_time,
         end_time,
         SUM(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM end_time - start_time))
           OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY start_time)
         - EXTRACT(HOUR FROM end_time - start_time) AS total_start_time,
         SUM(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM end_time - start_time))
           OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY start_time) AS total_end_time
  FROM   shift_time
  UNPIVOT (
    (start_time, end_time)
    FOR shift IN (
      (am_start_time, am_end_time) AS 'AM',
      (pm_start_time, pm_end_time) AS 'PM'
    )
  )
),
hours AS (
  SELECT name,
         project_number,
         hours,
         SUM(hours) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY project_number) - hours
           AS start_hour,
         SUM(hours) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY project_number)
           AS end_hour
  FROM   effective_hours
)
SELECT s.name,
       h.project_number,
       s.shift,
       s.start_time + NUMTODSINTERVAL(GREATEST(start_hour, total_start_time) - total_start_time, 'HOUR') AS start_time,
       s.start_time + NUMTODSINTERVAL(LEAST(end_hour, total_end_time) - total_start_time, 'HOUR') AS end_time
FROM   shifts s
       INNER JOIN hours h
       ON (   s.name = h.name
          AND s.total_start_time < h.end_hour
          AND s.total_end_time   > h.start_hour );
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE effective_hours (name, project_number, hours) AS
SELECT 'ALICE', 'PROJECT 1', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ALICE', 'PROJECT 2', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ALICE', 'PROJECT 3', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'BERYL', 'PROJECT 1', 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CAROL', 'PROJECT 1', 7 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE shift_time (name, AM_start_time, AM_end_time, PM_start_time, PM_end_time) AS
SELECT 'ALICE', INTERVAL '9' HOUR,  INTERVAL '12' HOUR, INTERVAL '14' HOUR, INTERVAL '17' HOUR FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'BERYL',  INTERVAL '10' HOUR, INTERVAL '12' HOUR, INTERVAL '13' HOUR, INTERVAL '16' HOUR FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CAROL',  INTERVAL '9' HOUR, INTERVAL '12' HOUR, INTERVAL '13' HOUR, INTERVAL '19' HOUR FROM DUAL;
```

Which outputs:

| NAME | PROJECT_NUMBER | SHIFT | START_TIME | END_TIME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ALICE | PROJECT 2 | AM | +000000000 10:00:00.000000000 | +000000000 12:00:00.000000000 |
| ALICE | PROJECT 1 | AM | +000000000 09:00:00.000000000 | +000000000 10:00:00.000000000 |
| ALICE | PROJECT 3 | PM | +000000000 14:00:00.000000000 | +000000000 15:00:00.000000000 |
| BERYL | PROJECT 1 | AM | +000000000 10:00:00.000000000 | +000000000 12:00:00.000000000 |
| BERYL | PROJECT 1 | PM | +000000000 13:00:00.000000000 | +000000000 15:00:00.000000000 |
| CAROL | PROJECT 1 | AM | +000000000 09:00:00.000000000 | +000000000 12:00:00.000000000 |
| CAROL | PROJECT 1 | PM | +000000000 13:00:00.000000000 | +000000000 17:00:00.000000000 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/CuwzKRib)

Comment: Hi MT0, I am really impressed with your reactivity and the level of your SQL knowledge. I'm going to test this.
Thank you.

Comment: Hi MT0, it works fine, you are a pure genius ;)